# Difference and usage of 听看，听见，听到?

Tags: word-choice, difference

What's the difference between 听看，听见，听到? I heard someone use 听看 in reference to a song they would listen to? Does 听看 have a similar meaning to 看看 in that it means to have a quick look/listen?

Comment: answer to ＂Does 听看 have a similar meaning to 看看 in that it means to have a quick look＂：negative，see
dictionary，见，到 are complements of result (meaning action succeeded), 见 more specific than 到 (cf。＂实用现代汉语语法＂：＂见＂作结果补语，一般只用于感官动作动词＂看＂、＂瞧＂、＂瞅＂、＂望＂、＂听＂、＂闻＂之后）

Answer (score 7):

1, 听看 does not make sense as a word in mandarin, where did this come from?

2, 听见，听到 does not have semantic differences. people will use them interchangeably. follow your heart.

Comment: He probably misread 着 as 看.

Answer (score 2):

1. formally, [听看 means 听 (to listen), and 着 implies a continuous aspect](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Aspect_particle_%22zhe%22) (e.g. "i was listening" rather then "i listened"). that said, the construct seems to be more idiomatic. i tend to see it more in verbal vernacular, when you are asking someone to listen to you. here is an example (with translation) from the [subtitles of the 2001 movie shrek](https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search2/sublanguageid-chi,zht,eng/moviename-shrek) (00:09:14):

   - 听着  驴子  看看我  我是什么?
   - tīng zhāo lǘzi. kànkan wǒ. wǒ shì shénme?
   - Listen, little donkey. Take a look at me. What am I?
2. 听见 and 听到 are interchangeable. 听 indicates that you are listening (trying to hear). [both 见 and 到 indicate that the listening is "accomplished" in some sense](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Result_complements_%22dao%22_and_%22jian%22).  so 听到 means that you are listening and able to hear what you are listening for. as such, both are often translated as "hear", thereby highlighting the result of listening (hearing) and discarding the information about the hearing person's intent (listening). here are examples again from the subtitles of shrek (01:01:44 and 01:13:02):

   - 你能听到我吗? 小驴
   - nǐ néng tīngdào wǒ ma ? xiǎo lǘ!
   - Can you hear me? Donkey!
   - 我听见你们俩的谈话了
   - wǒ tīngjiàn nǐmen liǎ de tánhuà le
   - I heard the two of you talking.

also see: [What is the difference between 听到、听过 and 听说?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/6655/what-is-the-difference-between-%E5%90%AC%E5%88%B0-%E5%90%AC%E8%BF%87-and-%E5%90%AC%E8%AF%B4)

Answer (score 1):

听听看 means listen to (listen to and see if it is any good).

Comment: Yes, that would make sense too since we tend to eat consonants and make it "ting 'ing kan"